# Set values of an array according to a logical array in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, set

I have an array `a=np.array([ -1, 20, 34, 4, 5, -60, -7, 8])` , I want to test 2 conditions in this way: `p=np.logical_or(a<=5, a>=25)` . In this manner I have a logical array `(True-False, 0-1)` .
Now I want to set the values of the array a which satisfy the True condition of p to a predefined value, as example NaN.

```
p
array([ True, False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

I want:

```
value=array([NaN, 20, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 8])
```

How can I made it?

Answer (score 4):

Use [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
>>> np.where((a<=5) | (a>=25), np.nan, a)
array([ nan,  20.,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,   8.])
>>> p = np.logical_or(a<=5, a>=25)
>>> np.where(p, np.nan, a)
array([ nan,  20.,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,   8.])
```

or create a new array of type float using `a` and assign `np.nan` to its indices using `p`:

```
>>> a_ = a.astype(float)
>>> a_[p] = np.nan
>>> a_
array([ nan,  20.,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,   8.])
```